# Creating a web UI for an ftp file server that can archive folders as ZIP to download

Tags: javascript, user-interface, ftp, zip, ftp-client

I'm trying to create a file server to serve a bunch of files for download and have a web-based UI to search/filter and download the files.

Right now i'm using a basic FTP server and i'm planning to create a simple (flask+js) web app that will redirect me to the ftp url for the selected file so it can be downloaded. The web app is needed so I can create my own tagging and filtering system.

However, i'm having trouble finding out how to download whole directories and folders as a zip. Basically like how google drive can have a "Download as zip" function while still keeping the raw folder available for browsing.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This involves working with "[blobs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)", a JavaScript way of dealing with streamable binary data.

I haven't tried this particular library myself, but there's an article here about using the [JSZip library](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) specifically for the kind of thing I think you're talking about: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-zip

Comment: but this only works when im trying to zip a local file. however i want to download a folder from an ftp server as a zip. ive read that ftp doesn't support this but i was hoping there would be a workaround to make it happen. i thought that if google drive has this feature it means that its possible.

Comment: You can do this, but it'll be the job of your code to recursively read through the contents of the FTP folder, then use the JSZip library to bundle up all of those files as a .zip file in a blob.